# Is it possible to have two seperate accounts to get firebase crashlytics for single app

Tags: android, firebase

I have one android app for which firebase crashlytics is already integrated and it's up and working fine. But, that firebase account is with my client so, only client can see the details of crashes of the app and ofcourse our client cannot give their credentials to see the details of crashes. Is it possible to have another account to get the crashlytics of the same app?. Please help with any other alternative if firebase is not providing that facility. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The client can give you access to their own account

Answer (score 0):

We can add more users to an existing Firebase project. The user who created the project is by default added as the "owner" of the project. You may add a new user by,

1. Navigate to your project in the Firebase Console. Go to "Project Overview" and select "Users and permissions"

[image]

2. Enter the email address and select the "role" of that user.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I have a doubt if we add member and if we just give view access then we still cant see the crashlytics and if we give access as a owner then that is nothing but giving entire access itself so I dont think any client will agree for this. Can you please help me with any other alternative?.